# how to activate Java 8u51 plugin on Firefox?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, java, openjdk, jdk

Can you please advise. I tried to install Java 8u51 plugin. But I'm not able to activate it. Please see below what I get in terminal:

```
$ java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection   Path   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
0           /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071  auto mode
1           /opt/java/32/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java               1     manual mode
2           /opt/jre/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java                   1000  manual mode
3           /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061  manual mode
4           /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071  manual mode
```

Can you please advise how I can get my Java working on Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Install Oracle java this way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```